# Algorithm for parallel program to find the number of of "hidden" objects in matrix with MPI, OpenMP and CUDA

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, mpi, openmp

For my studies I need to write an **effective parallel program** to find an object that not visible for the maximum number of other objects at the given moment within a matrix.

Main characteristics:

- MPI with 3 computers
- OpenMP to use 4 cores on each PC
- Optionally CUDA

Data:

- The Objects are placed in the matrix of size AxB.
- I have a large file with coordinates of the objects and their timestamps.
- The objects are flights, but velocity is constant.

The problem:

If I draw a line from the center of the cell of one object (C1) to the center of the cell with another object (C3) and the line cross a cell with additional object (C2) this means:

- C1 do not see C3
- C3 do not see C1

[image: problem]

My question:

Is there any known algorithm for similar problem (may be some problem in graphics), that I can look on the solution?

Thank you for any help.

**Update: final solution**
https://github.com/anod/CriticalLevelCalculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is simple maths.

1. Take 2 points p1, and p2.
2. Find their linear equation.
3. Compare with all the points, if any of them belongs to that equation and are between p1 and 2.
4. If some points are in the way, so p1 and p2 have one more vote to be the *not visible*.

Hope That could help you.

Comment: Thank you, that what I think also, just was thinking if I will represent the data some way there is possible be solution that more efficient or fit an existing parallel algorithm